# Add a single control to multiple placeholders

Tags: asp.net-placeholder

There are two placeholders in my page.aspx:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

// Other tags

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I've created one HtmlGenericControl in page.aspx.cs and want to add it in both PlaceHolders:

```
HtmlGenericControl NewControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
NewControl.ID = "newDIV";
NewControl.Attributes.Add("class", "myClass");
NewControl.InnerHtml = "**myContent**";
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(NewControl);
PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(NewControl);
```

The problem is that just the **last Add** takes effect !

The Line

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(NewControl);
```

does not work !

Am I wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A control cannot be a child of more than 1 parent control. You must create your HtmlGenericControl twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A control cannot be a child of more than 1 parent control. You must create your HtmlGenericControl twice:

```
Func<HtmlGenericControl> createControl = () => {
    HtmlGenericControl newControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    newControl.ID = "newDIV";
    newControl.Attributes.Add("class", "myClass");
    newControl.InnerHtml = "**myContent**";
    return newControl;
};

PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add( createControl() );
PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add( createControl() );
```